# Return response from a kernel event listener

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using the *OAuth2 Server Bundle* and I want to authenticate the user for all methods in my controller. It's very similar to the use case done in the documentation [How to Setup before and after Filters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html), except that I want to return the response instead of throwing an exception.

`onKernelController` with `FilterControllerEvent` gives me access to the controller so I can access *OAuth2 Server Bundle's* response method. But I can't return any response in there. I can return a response in `onKernelController` using `GetResponseEvent`, but it gets called before `onKernelController`.

I looked into `kernel.exception` too but `getResponse()` returns different error messages so I rather not just throw an ambiguous exception.

What's the best practice for what I am trying to accomplish?

This is my code:

```
public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
    $controller = $event->getController();

    if ($controller[0] instanceof \Foo\Bundle\AuthBundle\Controller\TokenAuthenticatedController) {

        $server = $controller[0]->get('oauth2.server');
        $request = $controller[0]->get('oauth2.request');
        $response = $controller[0]->get('oauth2.response');

        if (!$server->verifyResourceRequest($request, $response)) {
            return $server->getResponse();
        }
    }
}

public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $event->setResponse(new Response('Some response', 501));
}
```

Comment: Have you already see [this article](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/12/prevent-controller-execution-with-annotations-and-return-a-custom-response/)?

Comment: No I haven't. But that's exactly what I don't want to do. I.e throw an exception in `onFilterController` and pick it up in `onKernelException`. But it seems like this is the "right" way to do it. Thanks for posting the article.

Comment: the problem, of course, is that you can't set the response on the event you try to manage, check if you can manage the `GetResponseForControllerResultEvent` event. Hope this help

Comment: @Matteo: Feel free to post that as an answer, and I will accept it. It seems that is the way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the EventListener Approach you can't return a response but you must set it on the event itself.

The problem is that the Event `FilterControllerEvent` can't manage a returned response, so a better approach is to manage(listen for) the  [GetResponseForControllerResultEvent](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Event/GetResponseForControllerResultEvent.html) where you can set a response and stop the propagation.

Hope this help.

Comment: Beware though: `GetResponseForControllerResultEvent` is fired **only** if the Controller does not return a `Response` object. This also means that the Controller is **always** called, regardless of what your event listener is doing, since it's only being called afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

This post is a bit dated, but here is the solution for other people who read it.

```
public function onKernelController(ControllerEvent $event)
{
    // If your condition is met, return a response
    $response = new Response('Your response');
    $event->setController(function () use ($response) {
        return $response;
    });
}
```